# Angular 1.5.8: Why does the child component of ng-repeat not render?

Tags: angularjs

Anyone know why the child-view is not rendering in the following Plunk?

https://plnkr.co/edit/NQU9fmRvGS3U0rLYSmKa?p=preview

basically have this:

```
data = [...]
parent-view data="$ctrl.data"
  li ng-repeat="item in data"
    child-view data="item"
```

Comment: In your view.js you're defining the parent as a `.component()`, and the  child using `.directive()` -- but with the syntax for `.component()` . Switching the child to `.component()` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Daniel mentioned in his comment, you need to switch your `.directive` definitions to `.component`

See updated Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/3FFjDMut4gfBLDYbg0fJ?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! I missed that one in the plunk. But your solution lead me to the REAL problem I was having....angular.module('app.views', []) in the root file, then angular.module('app.views', []) in the child file. changed both to angular.module('app.views').

Comment: err, um ('app.rootview', []) setter and ('app.childView', []) setter